# Copula generation (Gaussian, t and Gumbel) with the help of correlation matrix using R

Tags: r, distributions, normal-distribution, copula, gumbel-distribution

I have a set of data of 2 variates. I have generated correlation matrix between the variates. Using `copula` package of R, I computed t-copula using correlation matrix. I used the following technique for that:

1. With the help of correlation matrix for example let it be `corr_mat`, I computed parameter vector, lets say `param_vect`.
2. Then I computed `tcopula` object, let it be `t_object`, using
   `tCopula(param_vect, dim =..., dispstr="un", df =...)`
3. Lastly I simulated 1000 sample from the copula using `rcopula(1000,t_object)`.

The above procedure works fine for t-copula. Can someone please suggest me amethod to simulate samples from the Gaussian and Gumbell copulas? I  tried with the `gumbelcopula` function, but it fails with errors. 
Could anyone one suggest the method to simulate copula using correlation matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Correlation is problematic because it depends on the marginal distribution.

Change the margins (which doesn't alter the copula) and the correlation changes. A specific correlation is not associated with a given copula and vice-versa.

The correlation matrix that is an input to a t-copula doesn't define the correlation of the resulting variables that have that copula, so you may not be achieving what you think you are when you use the t-copula function. Similarly with the correlation in a Gaussian copula - you can specify the value of the parameter $\rho$, but that doesn't mean that the correlation of the variables you generate with that Gaussian copula is $\rho$. If they also have Gaussian margins, then the correlation is $\rho$, otherwise it will generally not be $\rho$, but some function of it that depends on what the margins are.

This is why many people focus on nonparametric correlations like Kendall's tau or Spearman's rho. Those *are* specified by a given copula, and apply to any (continuous) margin.

For a number of specific copula families there are often relatively simple relationships between the parameters of the family and one or both of those common measures of nonparametric correlation.

Comment: Hi Glen
You have provided with the correct conceptual flaw in my approach. But as I am newbie in this environment so I tried to take the very simple approach of going through correlation matrix route. It would nice of you if you can share the algorithm of your approach.

Comment: I didn't mention any approach. You *could* use the relationship between the copula and the nonparametric correlation to infer a parameter value, but that's not necessarily the best choice. So for example, with the Gumbel, the parameter $\alpha = \frac{1}{1-\tau}$, so the sample value $\hat\tau$ could be used to back out an estimate of $\alpha$, but I believe that's not the most common way to do it with the Gumbel.